# Return non-zero element

Tags: python, list-comprehension

```
remainders = [1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
nonzero_remainders = [r for r in remainders if r]
```

Why does nonzero_remainders list comprehension exclude 0?
I didn't understand why the expression is excluding 0.

Comment: What do you think `if r` does?

Comment: Because zero value is considered as false. Check out the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) about truthy and falsy values.